# How to publish asp.net project + Sql [First Migration] on azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, azure

I have a project and want to publish it to `azure` . I tried to publish it but I have no idea.

I have no problem with publishing my project, but how I can upload or publish my sql database that I created using entity framework code first migration with my project, because I have data on it also the tables , so anyone have Idea of instructions how I can publish my project with the sql database?

**Update**: I Published my project , after I created a db and web app on azure but I have a problem with editing my connection string , if someone can help with that ..

My deafault connection string :

```
    <add name="SmartBookLibraryModel1" connectionString="data source=FIRAS-JC\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=SBL;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

and this connection string I got from the sql database from azure :

```
Server=tcp:jhm8n1ya03.database.windows.net,1433;Database=smtebooAIkF3XGJh;User ID=Firasmsw@jhm8n1ya03;Password={your_password_here};Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;
```

how the new one should be look ??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to create the azure database. Add the connection string to your configuration files (web.config). Make sure the user you use in the connection string has the rights to do the changes to the database. And then deploy the project to azure.
When the application starts, the migrations will be applied to the database.

[get started migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Comment: Thank you , I have a question , how I can change the connection string . I mean where I can get the new connection string ? and should I replace it on the old one ?

Comment: I created db and deployed the project , and finished without error . I still did not change anything related to connection string . and got this error :
http://smtebooks.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: also I noticed that the controller files did not uploaded !